# What IE8 setting might cause small text to be rendered as normal-sized text (some "minimum font size to display" setting)?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

IE8 (on Windows 7) is not rendering the very smallest fonts on our website as small, but rather as normal size (100% of normal text size).

However, on a fresh install of Windows 7 (in virtual pc) with fresh IE8 installed, it renders properly.

I'm guessing there is some setting afoul. I've checked:

- Page> Zoom 100%
- Page> Text Size : Medium